# What is an artifact set?

Tags: magicka-2

I just finished a bossfight and unlocked the "Video Mode #2" artifact set. What are they? Is it something like rockstar editor? How can I enter it?
[image: Unlocked! Video Mode #2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've finished the story in Normal mode, you unlock the "Custom artifact" difficulty in the "Adventure" menu.

[image: Difficulty menu]

In this section, you can customise your gameplay by adding elements you have unlocked.

[image: Custom artifacts]